# risk of flooding in petra in november

Tags: safety, middle-east, natural-disasters, petra

My tentative plans have me in Egypt from November 12 - November 23. I was thinking it could be cool to visit Petra before hand. Maybe like November 9 - November 11 or some such.

The concern I have with this is...  last year, on November 10, Petra flooded and a bunch of tourists died and a bunch more had to be evacuated:

https://www.bbc.com/news/av/world-middle-east-46162772/deadly-flash-floods-hit-jordan-s-iconic-city-of-petra

[According to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petra#Climate), the average rainfall in Petra in November is 0.6in. It's hard to imagine flash flooding with that little rain but idk.

My question is...  how likely is Petra to flood in early November? Were the flash floods from last year an aberration or are they fairly common in early November?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Petra is in the desert, so rain is rare, but it's also in a dry river bed (*wadi*) so flash flooding after heavy rain is possible.  It's worth noting this only affects the actual monument, the town of Petra where all the hotels etc are is located above the valley and is not subject to floods

So avoiding flash floods is simple enough: don't go into the valley after heavy rain upstream.  (This applies to wadis anywhere, not just Petra.)

Comment: Heavy rain might be happening uphill, so it may not be that easy.